# Remove duplicates not working

Tags: c#, .net

Hi can i know why this code not working, it's working but it will also remove non duplicates entry and for some lists it will throw some error

ex:

This list working but it will also remove http://test1.com

```
http://test.com
http://test.com
http://test1.com
http://1test.com
```

And with this lists will throw this "System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled" error

```
http://test.com
http://test.com
http://test1.com
http://1test.com
http://etest.com
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog buka = new OpenFileDialog();
    buka.InitialDirectory = "";
    buka.Filter = "Text files(*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    buka.FilterIndex = 2;
    buka.RestoreDirectory = true;
    buka.Title = "Cari";

    buka.ShowDialog();
    string bukafile = buka.FileName;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bukafile))
    {
        StreamReader isiFile = File.OpenText(bukafile);
        while (isiFile.Peek() != -1)
        {
            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(isiFile.ReadLine()))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(isiFile.ReadLine());
            }
        }
            isiFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should cache the line from `isiFile.ReadLine()` so you compare the same line as you're adding.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog buka = new OpenFileDialog();
    buka.InitialDirectory = "";
    buka.Filter = "Text files(*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    buka.FilterIndex = 2;
    buka.RestoreDirectory = true;
    buka.Title = "Cari";

    buka.ShowDialog();
    string bukafile = buka.FileName;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bukafile))
    {
        StreamReader isiFile = File.OpenText(bukafile);
        while (isiFile.Peek() != -1)
        {
            // use local variable here
            string line = isiFile.ReadLine();
            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(line))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
            isiFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah already think to do this but just don't know how to change, tried foreach but since im new to this it don't work :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a very huge file you could replace a lot of your code using

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(bukafile).Distinct();
listBox1.DataSource = lines.ToList();
```

Comment: What's the point in the (first) `ToList` call?  `Distinct` doesn't care if the input is a list or any other type of enumerable, so you're taking the time and effort of creating, growing, populating a list just to throw it away.  Additionally, you can use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` to stream the input.  The result is the same, but you won't be keeping duplicate entries in memory.  If there are few duplicates the result is small, but if there are a lot you use a *lot* less memory.

Comment: Why would the performance be "much better"? There's no magic behind LINQ, it still needs to read lines and compare them. I would agree that the *readability* is much better though, and the intention of the code is easier to spot than the original.

Comment: Difficult to say, you need to test with your environment but I think you are pretty safe with a less than 1MB file

Comment: @Patrick `Distinct` is O(N) while the op solution is O(N²). So on large collections it would make a big difference.

Comment: @Magnus: Well then it makes sense. When you think about it it's kind of obvious that a hashmap is used for distinct.. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading two lines, one for each `ReadLine()` call.  You use the first line to do the `.Contains` check, and the second line to add to the listbox.  These two lines aren't related to each other in any way.

So for the first list, you first check if `http://test.com`, the first line, is in the listbox.  It isn't, so you read the next line, coincidentally also `http://test.com`, and add that to the listbox.  Then, you check if `http://test1.com` is in the listbox, find that it isn't, and then proceed to add `http://1test.com` to the listbox.

For the second list, you have an odd number of entries, so the final call to `ReadLine` returns, I'm guessing, null, which you can't add to the listbox.

The fix is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog buka = new OpenFileDialog();
    buka.InitialDirectory = "";
    buka.Filter = "Text files(*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    buka.FilterIndex = 2;
    buka.RestoreDirectory = true;
    buka.Title = "Cari";

    buka.ShowDialog();
    string bukafile = buka.FileName;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bukafile))
    {
        StreamReader isiFile = File.OpenText(bukafile);
        while (isiFile.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string line = isiFile.ReadLine();
            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(line))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
            isiFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i see nice explanation but i can't accept your answer since i got the solution from above answer first thanks will try to figure this out :)